# SPFieldDateTime change Value to none

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

So i have a SPFieldDateTime, and its default value is set to (none), i.e. null.
Now some people use this to sort for specific ListItems (like "time finished" -> sort fot not null items you get all unfinished items).
People got quite used to it, built something around it, but now i have a problem: Some guys wrote something into this field even though they werent finished, now everything is broken, and i was asked to set those fields to null via powershell.
No Problem i said, but now it is! You cannot set a SPFieldDateTime to null. Or can you?

```
$item["DateTimeField"] = $null;
$item["DateTimeField"] = "";
```

None of these work. Anybody got an idea?

edit: I wanna try something like $item.Fields["DateTimeField"].Delete() but that only deletes the Column from the whole list..

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right path, you just need to update the item after making the change. The following should work:

```
$item["DateTimeField"] = $null
$item.Update()
```